# Explaining $\beta_p$ curve for Van der waals gas

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

Given the Van der waals gas
$$\left(p+\frac{a}{V^2}\right)\left(V-b\right)=RT$$
in standard notations. I tried finding isobaric expansivity $\beta_p$ which is defined as
$$\beta_p\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$
I find it for van der Waals gas. It's turn out after a little calculation
$$\beta_p=\frac{1}{T}\left(1+\frac{b}{V-b}-\frac{2a}{pV^2+a}\right)^{-1}$$
and using the natural scale as critical point (I'm not sure if it's good to use it). I found it to be
$$\tilde \beta_p=\frac{1}{\widetilde{T}}\left(1+\frac{1}{3\widetilde{V}-1}-\frac{6}{\tilde p \widetilde V^2+3}\right)^{-1}$$
Using $$\left(\tilde p +\frac{3}{\widetilde V^2}\right)=\frac{8\widetilde T}{3\widetilde V-1} $$
$$\tilde \beta_p=\frac{3\widetilde V-1}{8}\left(\tilde p +\frac{3}{\widetilde V^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3\widetilde{V}-1}-\frac{6}{\tilde p \widetilde V^2+3}\right)^{-1}$$
The plot of this look like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/krpybj7u89).

[image]

The above is a plot of $\tilde \beta$ Vs $\widetilde V$ at $\tilde p=0.3$ and $\widetilde T=0.5$.

Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: This plot has a logic problem, Since it is a Van der Waal's gas, it should follow the Van der Waal's equation. Therefore, after you fixed P and T, the volume is also fixed by the equation. You can only fix either P or T, the other variable will be solved from the equation using the given value V.

Comment: Eliminate P from your equation, and obtain a function of T and V.

Comment: @ytlu I have replaced $T$ for other two as it was much easier. Can you explain it not? What's going on?

Comment: @Young Kindachi What are the values of parameters $a$ and $b$ for this plot?

Comment: See the units I'm using. There are not a and b dependence.

Answer (score 1):

The Van der Waal's equation try to take into account two effects: 1. the finite volume occupied by moleculars, thus the effective vloume becomes smaller by a parameter $b$; and 2. the attractive force between moleculars, which introduce another parameter $a$ to reduce the resultant potential.

For most of gases, these parameters are small, the paramater $b$ reduces less that $1$ percent of the free gas (22.4 liters per mole), and the Van der Waal's equation is also a near-free gas equation. It doesn't apply to condition of very small volume.

Nerverthless, lets examine your result from a pure math point of view. Your quick fluctuated curve at small volume is not hard to understand: it is simple the roots of the denominator in the expression of isobaric thermal exapnsion coefficient, $\beta_p$.

The denominator of  $\beta_p$ (all units are in your scale.)
$$
   v^2 \{ (3 v - 1) (p v^2 + 3) + (p v^2 +3) - 6 (3 v - 1) \} \tag{1}
$$
Eq. (1) is polynomial of $v$ of order 5. It has 5 roots, a double root at $v= 0$, two positive roots and one negative root. The following figure plots the value of denominator (besides the term $v^2$) for $p=0.3$ in the range $-5 < v < 5$:

[image]

Denominator $  (3 v - 1) (p v^2 + 3) + (p v^2 +3) - 6 (3 v - 1) $

Each root corresponding to the divergence of $\beta_p$ in your curve. Are there physical interpretation for this? I have to say  *NO* , since the region of small volume (and of course neither negative volume) is not where Van der Waals equation is supposing to apply.

Looking into the math reason. Lets examine the temperature $T$ as function of $v$ for a fixed $p=0.3$. The turning points of $T$ for a given $p$ can again be seen from the $T$ vs $v$ plot.

[image]

$T$ as function of $v$ for $p = 0.3$ at $v$ near 0.7.

At this region, the temperature reaches a maximum at $T=0.7$, which cause the divergence of $\beta_p$ at this poistion.

Similarly, at $v$ near 2.75, $T$ reaches a local mimimum, which cause the other divergence of $\beta_p$.

[image]

Minimum of $T$ at $v$ near 2.75.

But the fluctuation of temperature is very small. Temperature is basically flat in large scale plot. This small fluctuation of temperature cause a divergence of $\beta_p$ is certainly out of the accuracy of Van der Waals potential can provided. The pursuing of its meaning is not reasonable, as far as I can see.